# Delegating hash-function to uninitialized delegates in hibernate causes changing hashCode

Tags: java, hibernate, initialization, hashcode

I have a problem with `hashCode()` that delegates to uninitialized objects using hibernate.

My data-model looks as follows (the following code is highly pruned to stress the problem and thus broken, do not replicate!):

```
class Compound {
  @FetchType.EAGER
  Set<Part> parts = new HashSet<Part>();

  String someUniqueName;

  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((getSomeUniqueName() == null) ? 0 : getSomeUniqueName().hashCode());
    return result;
  }
}

class Part {
  Compound compound;

  String someUniqueName;

  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((getCompound() == null) ? 0 : getCompound().hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((getSomeUniqueName() == null) ? 0 : getSomeUniqueName().hashCode());
    return result;
  }
}
```

Please note that the implementation of `hashCode()` thoroughly follows the advice as given [in the hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode).

Now if I load an object of type `Compound`, it eagerly loads the `HasSet` with the parts. This calls the `hashCode()` on the parts, which in turn calls the `hashCode()` on the compound. However the problem is that at this point, not all values that are considered for creating the hashCode of the compound are yet available. Therefore, the hashCode of the parts *changes* after initialization is complete, thus braking the contract of the `HashSet` and leading to all kinds of difficult-to-track-down errors (like e.g. having the same object in the parts set twice).

So my question is: What is the simplest solution to avoid this problem (I'd like to avoid writing classes for custom loading/initialization)? Do I do anything wrong here entirely?

**Edit**: Am I missing something here? This seems to be a basic problem, why don't I find anything about it anywhere?

> Instead of using the database identifier for the equality comparison,
>   you should use a set of properties for equals() that identify your
>   individual objects. [...] No need to use the persistent identifier, the so
>   called "business key" is much better. It's a natural key, but this
>   time there is nothing wrong in using it! ([article from hibernate](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode))

And

> It is recommended that you implement equals() and hashCode() using
>   Business key equality. Business key equality means that the equals()
>   method compares only the properties that form the business key. It is
>   a key that would identify our instance in the real world (a natural
>   candidate key). ([hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode))

**Edit:** This is the stack trace when the loading happens (in case this helps). At that point in time, the attribute `someUniqueName` is null and thus the hashCode is calculated wrongly.

```
Compound.getSomeUniqueName() line: 263  
Compound.hashCode() line: 286   
Part.hashCode() line: 123   
HashMap<K,V>.put(K, V) line: 372    
HashSet<E>.add(E) line: 200 
HashSet<E>(AbstractCollection<E>).addAll(Collection<? extends E>) line: 305 
PersistentSet.endRead() line: 352   
CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(LoadingCollectionEntry, CollectionPersister) line: 261   
CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionPersister, List) line: 246    
CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionPersister) line: 219  
EntityLoader(Loader).endCollectionLoad(Object, SessionImplementor, CollectionPersister) line: 1005  
EntityLoader(Loader).initializeEntitiesAndCollections(List, Object, SessionImplementor, boolean) line: 993  
EntityLoader(Loader).doQuery(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters, boolean) line: 857    
EntityLoader(Loader).doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters, boolean) line: 274 
EntityLoader(Loader).loadEntity(SessionImplementor, Object, Type, Object, String, Serializable, EntityPersister, LockOptions) line: 2037    
EntityLoader(AbstractEntityLoader).load(SessionImplementor, Object, Object, Serializable, LockOptions) line: 86 
EntityLoader(AbstractEntityLoader).load(Serializable, Object, SessionImplementor, LockOptions) line: 76 
SingleTableEntityPersister(AbstractEntityPersister).load(Serializable, Object, LockOptions, SessionImplementor) line: 3293  
DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(LoadEvent, EntityPersister, EntityKey, LoadEventListener$LoadType) line: 496    
DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(LoadEvent, EntityPersister, EntityKey, LoadEventListener$LoadType) line: 477    
DefaultLoadEventListener.load(LoadEvent, EntityPersister, EntityKey, LoadEventListener$LoadType) line: 227  
DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(LoadEvent, EntityPersister, EntityKey, LoadEventListener$LoadType) line: 269   
DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(LoadEvent, LoadEventListener$LoadType) line: 152    
SessionImpl.fireLoad(LoadEvent, LoadEventListener$LoadType) line: 1090  
SessionImpl.internalLoad(String, Serializable, boolean, boolean) line: 1038 
ManyToOneType(EntityType).resolveIdentifier(Serializable, SessionImplementor) line: 630 
ManyToOneType(EntityType).resolve(Object, SessionImplementor, Object) line: 438 
TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(Object, boolean, SessionImplementor, PreLoadEvent, PostLoadEvent) line: 139   
QueryLoader(Loader).initializeEntitiesAndCollections(List, Object, SessionImplementor, boolean) line: 982   
QueryLoader(Loader).doQuery(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters, boolean) line: 857 
QueryLoader(Loader).doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters, boolean) line: 274  
QueryLoader(Loader).doList(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters) line: 2542  
QueryLoader(Loader).listIgnoreQueryCache(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters) line: 2276    
QueryLoader(Loader).list(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters, Set, Type[]) line: 2271   
QueryLoader.list(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters) line: 459 
QueryTranslatorImpl.list(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters) line: 365 
HQLQueryPlan.performList(QueryParameters, SessionImplementor) line: 196 
SessionImpl.list(String, QueryParameters) line: 1268    
QueryImpl.list() line: 102  
<my code where the query is executed>
```

Comment: *(not an answer to your question)*...  *"Please note that the implementation of hashCode thoroughly follows the advice as given in the hibernate documentation"* [sic].  The very article you link to composes the two hash codes by multiplying by a prime number before adding, which is much more common than just summing.  I'd recommend you *really* thoroughly follow that advice and multiply your *compound* by a prime number before doing the addition.  Either that or do XOR the two hashes.  But simply adding them typically augments the risks of collisions.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. The actual code does so. However this does not exactly help to illustrate the problem, which is why I removed it. As the note above explains: "*the following code is highly pruned to stress the problem*".

Comment: It is not the most ideal solution, but it might solve your problem.  For the various hashing collections, the first call is to hashCode *as an optimization*.  Then equals() is called if the hash codes are equal.  You could have hashCode() always return 1, assuming your equals() method does not suffer from the same issue (e.g., an uninitialized value of compound.someUniqueValue).  What does the equals() method look like?

Comment: Hi! Why did you comment rather than answer? Mind the bounty! The equals methods are generated by Eclipse, using the same set of attributes as the hashCode methods. So they DO suffer from the same issue...

Comment: I am not completely sure, but you can try to check if the Object that Hibernate returns is really an Object you are looking for (Object.class), instanceof in this case will not be a good candidate because the proxy is a subclass. Hibernate will return a proxy if not all members are resolved and thus the hashcode/equals will break for sure.

Comment: Eugene, instanceof wouldn't break with hibernate proxies. Proxy classes extend the entities and (A instanceof B) == true if B is a subclass of A (as in this case).

However, if the equals method contains something like getClass() != obj.getClass(), then it would not work with proxies. Another point against Eclipse-generated equals methods.

Comment: I was saying about the test itself, to see if the returned object is a a proxy or not - in this case instanceof will NOT work because it will return true. If you re-read what I wrote, it will make sense. Basically it is the same as you said, but reversed ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a perfect legitimate use case, and indeed it should work. You would have the same problem in regular Java however, if you would set the 'parts' of the Compound object before you set the 'someUniqueName'.

So if you could convince hibernate to set the 'someUniqueName' property before the 'parts' property. Did you experiment with just reordering them in the java class? Or renaming 'parts' to 'zparts'? The hibernate docs just say the order is not guaranteed. I'd file a bug in hibernate to allow to enforce this order...

Another solution that might be easier:

```
class Part {
  public int hashCode() {
    //don't include getCompound().hashCode()
    return getSomeUniqueName() == null ? 0 : getSomeUniqueName().hashCode();
  }

  public boolean equals(Object o)
  {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!o instanceof Part) return false;

    Part part = (Part) o;

    if (getCompound() != null ? !getCompound().equals(part.getCompound()) : part.getCompound()!= null) 
       return false;
    if (getSomeUniqueName()!= null ? !getSomeUniqueName().equals(part.getSomeUniqueName()) : part.getSomeUniqueName()!= null)
        return false;

    return true;
  }
}
```

In the Compound.equals() make sure it also starts with

```
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    if (this == o) return true;
```

This should avoid the problem you are having now.

Every property in the hashCode() method should be in the equals() method, but not necessarily the other way around.

Comment: I realize that's the opposite of the title of the question which was: "Delegating hash-function" :-(

Comment: I tried to do reorder the properties and also renaming them ... didn't change anything. I get the feeling that collections are loaded before any other property. `equals()` indeed starts with the snipped you gave, however I do not see how this could help my problem?

Comment: I threw getCompound().hashCode() out of Part's hashCode(), so it's no longer delegating :-). That should avoid your problem. I kept it in the equals so that your business logic wouldn't break.

Comment: It is only a workaround, but it works. Thanks! Do you want to update your answer such that the solution is not in the comments? :-)

Answer (score 2):

From your question I understood that all your model properties which ever participating in `hashCode()` method were not loaded by default. In that case If you want all your properties to get loaded then you can follow to ways.

1. By calling getter methods in `hashCode()` of your model class as it's initializes/loads all model properties.
2. By using `sesstion.get()` instead of `session.load()` method, as it won't create any proxy and will load all properties of your model.
3. By setting `lazy="false"` for all your properties in mapping.

Hope this can solve your problem!

Comment: Thanks for the help. As for 1: is the same as proposed by abahgat and sadly doesn't help. For 2: I use 'query.list()' to retrieve the problematic object via query. And for 3: this is what I am currently doing and actually part of the problem...

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I was misleading ... the properties that participate in `hashCode()` ARE loaded, but only after hashCode has been calculated...

Answer (score 2):

I read in one of the comments to the question that you are letting Eclipse generate the `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

Did you do that for all the entities (`Part` and `Compound`)? I'm asking because if that's the case, those methods generally directly access the object properties (i.e. without calling the getter methods). They look like the following.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((prop == null) ? 0 : prop.hashCode());
    return result;
}
```

When using Hibernate, that often leads to problems like the one you are describing, because the uninitialized properties have default values (`null` for Objects, 0 for `int`s, and so on) **until the appropriate get method is called**, which causes the hibernate proxy to access the database and load the values you need to compute the proper values for the methods.

You can easily spot the problem if you fire up a debugger and inspect the properties on the first call to `hashCode()`.

If that happens, the easiest way to fix this is to modify your methods to use the get methods, like here:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((getProp() == null) ? 0 : getProp().hashCode());
    return result;
}
```

Another point worth noting: the Eclipse-generated equals method contains performs this check `getClass() != obj.getClass()` which is not appropriate for Hibernate entities which are extended by Hibernate proxies. I would replace that with an `instanceof` check.

Comment: +1 for the hint with the instanceof check. The other thing also sounds reasonable -- I'll check. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I am sorry to report that this did not solve my problem. I am within the bounds of a hibernate session and call the getter method -- and still get null instead of the actual value of the attribute. Is there anything else that I could do wrong in that regard?

Comment: Do you get null on all attributes or just on some of them? Maybe it could be helpful if you posted the actual code for your hashcode and equals methods. Just guessing.

Comment: I get `null` for all attributes except the id. And the compound object is actually a reall compound object -- and not a hibernate proxy! As requested I put the actual code of the `hashCode()` method, but I don't see how the `equals()` method can be of help... And I gave the stack trace of the call where `null` is returned where actually a value should have been...

Answer (score 2):

So why don't you use a list, instead of a set? I know it would be rather a workaround than a proper solution, but you wouldn't have to play with hashcodes at all.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. But in that specific situation, the implementation of the `hashCode()` and `equals()` allows me to just add any newly created object to the set, and if it is already contained, nothing happens and it is not persisted. That safes me a lot of extra code and/or database querying. A better solution would be to just return `0` as `hashCode()` and leave `equals()` as it is, resulting in the same as a list where equal values are not replaced upon insertion. However the solution as suggested by greyfairer is better...

Comment: Fair enough. Just please note that you shouldn't calculate hashCode() and equals() on fields which are not effectively final. Also I don't think that you should include compound when calculating either hashCode() or equals() for parts, as that's just the parent reference, not something that parts are built from.

Comment: It is true that parts are not built from components, however it could happen that two parts with the same attributes belong to two different components, in which situation the component is the only way to differentiate between them. In my situation (which is quite common I belief), parts are not unique in respect to 'the universe', but only in respect to 'their world' which is the compound.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility I thought about was following the advice as given in [this article](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html?page=1). They basically propose to not use hibernate (or rather the database) to generate IDs, but to use a UUID library to generate ones own ids and then use these IDs for `equals()` and `hashCode()`. Besides the problems mentioned in this article, it has some serious drawbacks for my current implementation: it will break my existing code! Every time I would create an `Part`-instance I first would have to query whether it already exists in the database and retrieve it if so. In my current implementation I just create `Parts` as I like and simply add them to the `Compound`. If the `Compound` already has such a part, everything works out automagically...

Answer (score 0):

I found a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008519/cascading-updates-with-business-key-equality-hibernate-best-practices). The basic idea of the solution is that the whole problem goes away as soon as you don't eagerly fetch the parts. Then the compound is already fully initialized when the parts are loaded. However this opens a whole different problem when working outside of sessions with detached objects...